# R pcurve: "two or less effect sizes"

Tags: r, modeling

I am conducting a meta-analysis and am trying to do a `p-curve` analysis to assess the presence of `p-hacking` in my data. I've run multiple analyses: one of all of my data (cognition) and several of the data broken down into domains of cognition. I tried to run the p-curve analysis on the overall model of cognition but it kicked back an error:

> Error in pcurve(meta_cognition) : 
>     Two or less effect sizes were detected, so p-curve analysis cannot be conducted.

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since I have 16 studies in that analysis. When I ran the code in one of my subanalyses, just to see if it worked, it did work (and that one only had 8 studies in it).

I thought there might be a chance that the data were somehow corrupted since the heterogeneity in that overall cognition meta-analysis model was I2 = 0.0% but in the subanalysis model, I2 = 94%...that's hugely different so I have a hard time believing that that's really a true effect.

So I suppose what I'm asking is:

1. Is there a reason why I might be getting this error on my p-curve analysis?
2. Is it possible that the data are corrupted somehow and that's why I'm getting 0.0% heterogeneity and an error with my p-curve analysis?

Thanks!

DATA (in data frame "data"):

```
Author <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","l","m","n","o","p","r")
N <- c(51,38,32,80,21,30,40,16,18,20,24,40,24,30,20,46)
TE <- c(0.16268,0.1853,-0.0365,0.379890909,0.130025,0.080893077,0.00453,0.3316,0.386,0.1017,0.009,0.322208333,0.336121667,0.822542857,0.14935,0.099075)
seTE <- c(0.28148,0.2299,0.25,0.227827273,0.30915,0.258907692,0.33103,0.36135,0.33785,0.3164,0.2887,0.34905,0.294816667,0.429471429,0.31765,0.208875)
```

CODE:

```
meta_cognition <- metagen(TE,
                   seTE,
                   data=data,
                   studlab=paste(data$Author),
                   comb.fixed=FALSE,
                   comb.random=TRUE,
                   method.tau="PM",
                   hakn=TRUE,
                   prediction=TRUE,
                   sm="SMD")
pcurve(meta_cognition)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the original coding for p-curve in the below link.
https://rdrr.io/github/MathiasHarrer/dmetar/src/R/pcurve2.R

Since I have a same problem... when I blocked with # the below command, the error message is gone away.. But I am not sure if this change is acceptable.

```
if (ksig <= 2){
  stop("Two or less effect sizes were detected, so p-curve analysis cannot be conducted.")
}
```